# Complicated Right-To-Left rule when defining a variable

Tags: c, variables, pointers, right-to-left

This is the question:
Using the Right-Left rule write the **C** definition of a variable named fubar that is a pointer to a function that 
takes a pointer to a char and returns a pointer to an array of 7 elements where each element is a pointer to a 
struct Sporcle.

My answer:

`*( (Sporcle*)[7] ) ( *fubar )( char* );`

Can anyone verify my answer and/or give me some pointers (no pun intended)?

**Edited Answer:**

`( (struct Sporcle*)[7] ) *( *fubar )( char* );`

**Final Answer**

`struct Sporcle *(*(*fubar)(char *))[7];`

Comment: I don't think you need the leftmost `*` do you?

Comment: Try to write down: pointer to an array of 7 elements where each element is a pointer to a struct Sporcle.

Comment: I was thrown off by the "returns a pointer to an array..." so I thought the return value itself should be a pointer, and that pointer would point to the seven Sporcle* elements.

Comment: `struct` keyword? Sorry for pointing out the most obvious edit.

Comment: @Beginner, would it be: (Sporcle*)[7] *fubar?
prelic, Thanks for catching that one!

Comment: Not quite, start with: a pointer to an array of 7 integers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Build it up a piece at a time:

A variable named `fubar`...

```
fubar
```

...that is a pointer...

```
*fubar
```

...to a function...

```
(*fubar)()
```

...that takes a pointer to a char...

```
(*fubar)(char *)
```

...and returns a pointer...

```
*(*fubar)(char *)
```

...to an array of 7 elements...

```
(*(*fubar)(char *))[7]
```

...where each element is a pointer...

```
*(*(*fubar)(char *))[7]
```

...to a `struct Sporcle`.

```
struct Sporcle *(*(*fubar)(char *))[7]
```

Your answer is incorrect - the thing on the left (called the *declaration specifier*) can only directly specify a type (a base type like `int`, a `struct`, `union`, `enum` or type name defined with `typedef`, optionally modified with a storage class specifier like `static` and/or a type specifier like `const`).  Pointer, array and function types are constructed by modifying the right-hand-side of the declaration (called the *declarator*), by adding `*`, `[]` or `()` to it.

In this case, the declaration specifier is `struct Sporcle` and the remainder is the declarator.

Comment: @lordmarinara: One thing to remember for your exam if you follow this method, is that if you go to apply a `[]` or `()` to a declarator and the last thing applied was a `*`, you must add parentheses around the existing declarator first.  (This is *always* the case when adding `()` to anything but the initial identifier, because you cannot have an array of functions or a function returning a function - only an array of function pointers or a function returning a function pointer).

Answer (score 3):

[`cdecl(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cdecl) is your friend:

```
cdecl> declare fubar as pointer to function(pointer to char) returning pointer to array 7 of pointer to struct Sporcle
struct Sporcle *(*(*fubar)(char *))[7]
```

Comment: Would the `[7]` need to be inside the first set of parentheses, because we're returning a pointer to an array of 7 elements, not 7 pointers? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: @lordmarinara - does the `declare` line make sense?  If it's right then the output is right... I'm not sure I get the distinction you're asking about.

Comment: We are trying here to help somebody to understand the topic and you are posting full solution...............

Comment: The solution isn't the important part.  The solution is to use a tool - in this case `cdecl` - instead of trying to parse this kind of garbage with your brain.  It's why we *have* computers.

Comment: You see, no interest from OP anymore. I would suspect this is due to your post.

Comment: Well, I don't want to rely on commands...I'm trying to understand it both for my exam and also, what is the use of using these commands if we don't know the reasoning behind them?

Comment: @lordmarinara The first * represents the pointer to the struct Sporcle. The second *, inside the first set of parentheses, represents the pointer to the array[7]. The third *, inside the second set of parentheses, represents the pointer to the function.

Comment: @lordmarinara - there is no reason do use such a complicated example to 'know the reasoning' behind something.  I hear what you're saying, but the practical solution to your problem is to use a tool made to solve the exact problem that you have.

Comment: @lordmarinara Exactly. First you understand, then you use computers. Feel free to ask other questions in chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5597/rbdecl Others are invited too!

Comment: *void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);* This is real declaration in real code it doesn't happens often, but it happens. How would you read it? Run cdecl each time?

Comment: Absolutely - are you saying you wouldn't?

Comment: No, because I *can* read them and last week I've teached my students to read them, now they also can.

Answer (score 3):

I won't comment on the validity, but I will offer a pointer: don't do that. Unless this is a purely intellectual exercise, refactor the declaration to make it less of a puzzle:

```
typedef Sporcle SevenSporcles[7];
SevenSporcles* (*fubar)(char*);
```